# jQuery: Change just the linear gradient over background image in an inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an inline style that applies a background image with linear gradient overlay to the containing `div`. The background image is dynamic so I have no way of knowing what the source URL is going to be. I also do not have access to change the script that is generating the markup. How can I change just the values of the linear gradient? I'm thinking I may need to extract the image URL from the inline style and then set the style to whatever I need?

```html
<div id="top" class="masthead" role="main" style="height:120vh;background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ),url('my-dynamic-image.jpg');background-size: cover;"></div>
```

This works, but is pretty ugly... Any ideas on cleaning this up?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var bg = $("#top").css("background");
 bg = bg.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
  $("#top").css({"background" : "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url(" + bg + ")", "background-size" : "cover"});
});
```